# i should commit changes everytime i make change in react project using VScode

Tags: reactjs, git, visual-studio-code, commit

[image]

I have a problem i'm new to React and every time i make change in my react project vscode tell me that i have to commit changes so i can run my project
Is there any solutions please ?

i can't run my react project without doing a commit first how i can get rid of this

Comment: You don't need to commit to run the code. Please add more detail and a text-based [mcve].

Comment: look at the image

Comment: where does it says you have to commit, you only see a list of files that are MODIFIED.

Answer (score 1):

You're in [vscode's source controll section](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/sourcecontrol/overview), so you're seeing each change you made from the previous commit.

You don't need to commit your changes to run your code, and you can simply change the 'tab' in the left sidebar to something else so you won't see it.